# Override DataContext in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I would like to make a UserControl which works only with a specific type of `DataContext`.
For that purpose I am doing something like this:

```
  public new AutoSuggestViewModel DataContext 
             { get { return (AutoSuggestViewModel)base.DataContext; } 
               set { base.DataContext = value; } }
```

This unfortunately tends to break .Net's reflection and causes the control to error in design view in Visual Studio and even worse when I use the control as a part of DataGridTemplateColumn's editing template causes errors and does not work properly, again due to broken reflection. It comes out as `AmbiguousMatchException` on `datagrid.BeginEdit()`

Does anybody know a work around this problem and how to achieve that.
And yes I have thought of using another property like `MyDataContext` which returns cast `DataContext` but I am looking for something more elegant if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Something more elegant would be to not impose on the `DataContext` at all. In fact, it doesn't make any sense to me why you'd want to do that. Why not just define a separate dependency property that *is* of the correct type? Then, consumers of your control can assign to it, either through a binding to their data context, or using any other standard WPF idiom.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your answer. Well I do not want to do that because users will get confused. Is this the datacontext or is that the datacontext which one to bind to? I have to then make sure that I keep both properties in sync. It is just noise.

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways to ensure that the right kind of object is assigned, you can for example create a property changed callback in the overriden metadata, check the type of the new value and throw an exception if you "do not like it".

Comment: Thanks although what you are saying will work it will not be enough. I want to have a typed object when I refer to DataContext otherwise I have to type cast it every time :)

Comment: I found the answer to my question but I could not post it because I am banned in by Stack Overflow for some reason. Thanks everyone for helping.